# Backlight on a Dell M1330

Tags: video, laptop, brightness

On my Dell M1330, there's 7 or 8 levels of backlight, but hitting [Fn]+[Up] and [Fn]+[Down] changes brightness level about 3 notches.
Any suggestions to make it change it only 1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an active bug for this issue at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/720912